# TCP does not receive sent data

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, recv

I've been testing a TCP client/listener.

My test opens 10 clients and accept them properly. Then it send some data through each of them. Only after **correctly send** all data it tries to receive it in the opposite side.

Here you can see the output from *strace* for the first 4 connections.
getpeername() is being used to check the connection on each side just after every *send* and *receive*. I already tried to perform the reception **inside a loop** until it gets something with **no effect**. So for clarity here I show results for single *recv* per connection.

```
send(4, "abcdefghij", 10, 0)            = 10
getpeername(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1366), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getpeername(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44847), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
send(6, "abcdefghij", 10, 0)            = 10
getpeername(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1366), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getpeername(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44848), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
send(8, "abcdefghij", 10, 0)            = 10
getpeername(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1366), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getpeername(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44849), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
send(10, "abcdefghij", 10, 0)           = 10
getpeername(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1366), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getpeername(11, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44850), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
[...]
recv(5, "", 10, 0)                      = 0
getpeername(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1366), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getpeername(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44847), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
recv(7, "abcdefghij", 10, 0)            = 10
getpeername(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1366), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getpeername(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44848), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
recv(9, "", 10, 0)                      = 0
getpeername(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1366), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getpeername(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44849), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
recv(11, "abcdefghij", 10, 0)           = 10
getpeername(10, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1366), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getpeername(11, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(44850), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
[...]
```

Notes:

- The reception of the sent messages happens only on the even connections (client 0, client 2, client 4...).
- Each connection uses blocking socket so recv() should wait forever.
- Failing connections are returning 0 (orderly shutdown) but the after check is telling me that the connection is still open... Am I correct?
- There is **no syscalls** (to close the sockets for example) between send block and receive block.

My questions are:

Where the connection is lost and why?

Comment: When `recv` returns zero, that means the other side normally closed the connection. You'd have to look at the other side to see why it did that.

Comment: "...but the after check is telling me that the connection is still open..." It sounds like you're using `getpeername()` to test the state of the connection. That's not what `getpeername()` does.

Comment: There is no 'after check' that can tell you a connection is still open when it isn't, and there is no reason why your code should even attempt to use one. You haven't posted any code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The sockets are being messed up with the application and the log shown in the question in not enough to debug the problem.

Capturing data with wire shark helped spotting the problem: Application duplicates sockets and due to logical issues the client uses the wrong ones to transmit.

Thank you for the tips: Has helped us to make improvements to the code.